# Integration involving piecewise function-see attached picture

Tags: integration

I have no clue where to start with this problem:

[image: Problem text]

Comment: Plot the function to get acquainted to it.

Comment: I did that but can't see how to relate it to g(x)

Comment: You can already answer 4.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate a piecewise fuction integate each piece.

$g(x) = \int_{-2}^x f(x) \, dx$ when $-3\leq x<0$

$g(x) = \int_{-2}^0 f(x) \,dx+ \int_0^x f(x)\, dx$ when $0\leq x < 6$, etc.

question 4 asks you to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.  You don't need to integrate before you differentiate.

Comment: This is what I got for 4: g(x) is increasing from -3 <= x <= 3

Comment: and 5: g(x) = (-x^(2) / 2) + (3x)

Comment: I agree with your answer to 4.  I would expect a piece wise function in the answer to 5.

Comment: But it's only asking for 0 ≤ x ≤ 6 right? And that's defined by a singe f(x) already

Comment: So it is, my mistake.  However, you still need to evaluate in the integral from -2 to 0 to find g(0).

Comment: Ok I tried that and got (-x^(2) / 2) + 3x + 8

Comment: $\int_{-2}^0 3 dx = 6$

Answer (score 0):

Listen to Yves, have a nice graph:

[image: f]

Here are the integrated pieces added, with (possibly wrong) integration constant $0$ for each piece:

[image: g with wrong integration constants]

So, what are the two properties of $g(x)$ that determine the correct choices for the integration constants?